# Why is Android Studio saying that "java" and "also" are "unresolved references"?

Tags: kotlin, google-mlkit

Currently, I am trying to implement Google's ML-Kit Vision's Barcode Scanning using these two tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju4AYKMe3Sw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIQ4_1B420g&t=90s

However, when putting the code into Android Studio, it states that **java** and **also** are unresolved references.

Here are where they are happening:

In ScannerActivity.kt, it states that **java** and **also** are unresolved references

```
    companion object {
        private var onScan : ((barcodes : List<Barcode>) -> Unit)? = null
        fun startScanner(context : Context, onScan: (barcodes: List<Barcode>)-> Unit) {
            this.onScan = onScan
            Intent(context, ScannerActivity::class.java).also {
                context.startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

In utils.kt, it states that **also** is an unresolved reference

```
fun Context.openPermissionSetting() {
    Intent(ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).also {
        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
        it.data = uri
        startActivity(it)
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried to create an extension function for **also**, but it cannot replicate the result that the tutorial has, and I have yet to find any solution for **java**. I am relatively new to Kotlin so I have no idea why this is happening, so if anyone has any ideas about why this is happening, please let me know.

Comment: Make sure the Kotlin plugin for Android Studio is up-to-date. You can find that in the settings. You can also try resyncing Gradle.

Comment: Ok nvm, I just restarted Android Studio, and now everything works fine

Comment: Classic Android Studio moment